# Cross-origin resource sharing setting isn't applied

Tags: angular, cross-domain, sensenet

I'm running `SenseNet 7.0.0`, running it with `ASP.NET 5.2.3` and I'm trying to run an api call from an Angular (Typescript) application. The Angular application runs on `localhost:4200` and the ASP.NET application runs on `localhost:55064`. I followed [this tutorial](https://community.sensenet.com/docs/install-sn-from-nuget/) for installing Sensenet and used [this tutorial](https://github.com/SenseNet/sn-webpages/blob/master/docs/install-webpages-from-nuget.md) for installing WebPages.

When I run an api call, I get this error:

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:55064' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

In the Content Explorer, I navigated to Root/System/Settings/Portal.settings. In the settings, I added the next code to the bottom of the file:

```
,
AllowedOriginDomains: [ "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:55064/" ]
```

I've also tried it with `[ "*" ]` and `[ "localhost" ]` instead of the two localhosts. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jvmr4.jpg) is a screenshot of the portal.properties file. I didn't forget to click the save button after changing the value. I expected this would fix the issue, but it didn't. Even though [it should not involve a restart](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Settings#What_is_a_setting.3F), I tried restarting the asp.net project and the server. That didn't resolve the problem either. I tried these solution because the [sensenet wiki](http://wiki.sensenet.com/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Allowed_origin_domains) and the [sensenet docs](https://community.sensenet.com/docs/cors/#allowed-origin-domains) stated that the url's of external applications should be added to the `AllowedOriginDomains` to whitelist them.

How do I fix the error above, which I get when I try to reach the API with an external program?

---

I don't think the Angular call is the issue here, but just in case:

Import statement:

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
```

HttpClient injection:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}
```

Angular api call:

```
testApiCall() {
  this.http.post(
    Configuration.ServerWithApiUrl + '/Odata.svc/(\'Root\')/Login?metadata=no',
    '"username" : "admin", "password" : "admin"')
    .subscribe(data => this.callResult = data);
}
```

Here is the error one more time:

```
The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:55064' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

---

This is an ajax call that is runned from the asp.net project on `localhost:55064`. That shows the succes message. <s>It also shows the succes message when I run it from a stand-alone html file.</s> It shows the error when I run it from a stand alone file too. In the error instead of "localhost:4200", it shows "null".

```
function testLoginCall() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Odata.svc/('Root')/Login?metadata=no",
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'username': "admin",
            'password': "admin"
        }),
        success: function (d) {
            console.log('You are logged in!');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a bug or limitation in Sensenet 7.0.0. You can see the status [here](https://github.com/SenseNet/sensenet/issues/258).

For now, a workaround is to [build the Angular project](https://angular.io/guide/deployment) using `ng build --base-href=~/Scripts/Angular` and paste the contents of the `dist` folder inside the `/Scripts/Angular` folder in the ASP.NET project. Then, replace the contents of the `_Layout.cshtml` file with the contents of the index.html file from the `dist` folder, put back the `@RenderBody()` in the `_Layout.cshtml`  and run the ASP.NET project

Both these api calls now work using the workaround:

```
testLoginApiCall() {
  this.http.post(
    Configuration.ServerWithApiUrl + '/Odata.svc/(\'Root\')/Login?metadata=no',
    '{"username" : "admin", "password" : "admin"}')
    .subscribe(
      data => console.log('Succes!', data),
      error => console.log('An error occured.', error));
}

testCreateWorkspaceCall() {
  this.http.post(
    Configuration.ServerWithApiUrl + 'OData.svc/(\'Root\')',
    'models=[{"__ContentType": "Workspace", "DisplayName": "Workspace"}]')
    .subscribe(
      data => console.log('Succes!', data),
      error => console.log('An error occured.', error));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `"localhost"` to the list of allowed origins in the settings file, **without the protocol and port**.

Comment: I tried that yesterday and tried it today again, but that didn't change the error message. This is how I've put it in the portal settings: https://imgur.com/a/9JTII

Comment: Can you please try to change one of these sites to use a different, non-localhost url?

Comment: I don't have a server available. The call seemed to work from an ajax call in a plain html file, which I ran without local host. The file was in the angular project and I just opened the html file in Chrome.

Comment: You do not have to have a server, you can register any random url (like mysite.com) in the local _hosts_ file on your machine and create a site in IIS with that url and point it to your web application's directory that has sensenet integrated in it.

Comment: This is of course a workaround, I think cors should work with those two localhost urls too, I suggest you create an issue for this at https://github.com/SenseNet/sensenet. My other concern is https, maybe that is also a requirement, we have to check. Maybe some browsers will work with cors only if the sites are secured.

Comment: I agree that changing the name of the front-end server to something else than localhost might not be optimal, as the wildcard ["*"] didn't work either. 

Good suggestion to submit the issue to github. [I've done that now.](https://github.com/SenseNet/sensenet/issues/258)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your requests do not match by headers or methods (POST, GET, PUT, etc)

Try this one or something similar in you way of conf.
`[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`

Comment: According to the [sensenet docs]() that should be the default behaviour. The docs also provide an example if you want to restrict the calls to a couple of methods or headers, I tried applying those too: `,
    AllowedMethods: [ "GET", "POST", "PATCH", "DELETE", "MERGE", "PUT" ],
 AllowedHeaders: [ "X-Authentication-Type", "X-Refresh-Data", "X-Access-Data", "X-Requested-With", "Authorization", "Content-Type" ]` It didn't solve the issue for me.

Comment: [sensenet docs](https://community.sensenet.com/docs/cors/#allowed-origin-domains) *

Comment: I've added the Angular api call

Answer (score 0):

As Miklós has mentioned one of the sites should have a different url than localhost. I've made a quick test and it worked without https so the steps are the follwowings:

1. Go to the IIS Manager and create a new site. Add the path of your sensenet install's webfolder as physical path and add a hostname other than localhost.

[image]

2. Add your custom hostname to your hosts file (\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)
3. Open sensenet's admin surface (aka. Content Explorer) and add this new url to the Default_Site's urllist (you can modify the list if you edit the Site content)

[image]

With these steps above I managed to fix the CORS error.